# Which is larger a "chasm" or a "gulf?"

Tags: word-choice, figures-of-speech

For the meaning:

> *figurative*: a profound difference
> between people, viewpoints, feelings,
> etc.

Is a chasm or a gulf generally interpreted as being a larger difference?

> **A:** The gulf between rich and poor has grown into a chasm?
>
> **B:** The difference is not merely a chasm,
> but a gulf.

Answer (score 2):

A sentence such as "The gulf between rich and poor has grown into a chasm." is really using a kind of mixed metaphor. As others have shown, a gulf is more about width, a chasm about depth. One is filled with water, the other air.

The temptation to use them together arises because both are geographical terms often co-opted to mean a large separation that is difficult to reduce or bridge. However we compare molehills with mountains - we don't compare mountains with rivulets or molehills with torrents.

It would be much better to express the thought using words which more naturally form a pair. For example: gulf and ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider their geological meanings.

A *chasm* is a deep opening in the earth.

A *gulf* is deep wide *chasm* of water.

By that logic, a gulf is really just a type of chasm. So it's impossible to determine which is actually larger.

However, if we are permitted to be unscientific: usually when I come across the two terms, I tend to think of a gulf as being much larger because the first chasm that comes to my mind is the Grand Canyon, whereas the first gulf that comes to mind is the Gulf of Mexico.

The gulf vs. chasm comparison is really very ambiguous.

Comment: I agree geologically. The perspective on Grand Canyon vs Gulf of Mexico is appreciated. Others?

Comment: A gulf is a large bay; that is, a large area of water mostly (but not entirely) enclosed by land. It doesn't have to be deep.

Answer (score 0):

"Gulf" is used metaphorically to mean a separation between two things with nothing in between. A chasm is a very evocative, dramatic word, implying a very deep, steep hole or crack in the earth. Chasm means impassible depth, gulf does not.

Comment: As for chasm being of impassable depth while gulf is not, one could argue also argue the reverse is true: see http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define:gulf (gulf) vs. http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define:chasm (chasm). There doesn't seem to a consensus on either.

Answer (score 0):

A *chasm* is more menacing since it is more difficult to cross than a *gulf*. For a *chasm* that's 300 m wide with equal height on both sides, you need at least a hot air balloon to cross. Whereas a *gulf* that's 300m wide can be crossed by swimming.

Answer (score 0):

*A: The gulf between rich and poor has grown into a chasm?
B: The difference is not merely a chasm, but a gulf.*

In a sense it doesn't matter which you use. What the reader will take from the context is that something considered significant is even more severe than was thought or existed.

Consider "the gulf between rich and poor". The reader imagines it as <---yay---> big. Now they're invited to consider a *chasmatic* version of that gulf. Regardless of any absolute meanings, the reader will widen and/or deeper the imagined gulf and consider the poor further distanced from the rich.

Comment: It's a good point, but I don't agree with your idea that the reader imagines "a chasmatic version of that gulf". The point is that both nouns indicate a scale, not that the one should be considered as a modifier of the other.